# How can I make an Intune Policy/Configuration to set a Network profile to Private on an AzureAD joined machine

Tags: networking, vpn, private-network, network-discovery, intune

How can I get a network to be automatically recognized as Private rather than Public?

Ideally, I would like to deploy this with Intune, but I haven't found an option that wasn't based off Script-Based solutions (like Proactive Remediations or a Scheduled Task that manually verify if you are on-premise and then Set-NetConnectionProfile to manually adjust the profile).

I have seen some suggestion of "[Network Boundary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/configuration/network-boundary-windows)" but that seems to be based more off protecting company information within those with [Windows Information Protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/windows-information-protection/create-wip-policy-using-intune-azure) rather than setting a Network to be "Trusted" but not "Private".

---

For some background, I'm working on an issue with Microsoft Always-On-VPN Per-User connection and Trusted Network Detection (TND).
From what I have seen in [some posts](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/19b0504e-4262-48bb-836d-965d2740c685/always-on-vpn-trusted-network-detection-not-working-on-wired-connection), if the network profile of a network is detected as "Public" then Trusted Network Detection will not apply.

A lot of what I have found involves the machine verifying a domain, and the Network Profile getting marked as "Domain", but there is no on-premise domain for it to find in this environment.

The only source I have found about the Private/Public network issue with TND is this [one TechNet post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/19b0504e-4262-48bb-836d-965d2740c685/always-on-vpn-trusted-network-detection-not-working-on-wired-connection), and not any definitive documentation.